# Can I set InputType to "textCapSentences" Delphi XE5

Tags: android, delphi, android-softkeyboard, delphi-xe5

I need to capitalize first letter In sentences then user typing string in Edit like I can do it in Eclipse : "android:inputType="textCapSentences"

How can I do it in XE5?

Or may be some other way to change Shift status on virtual keyboard in XE5?

Answer (score 2):

The `textCapSentences` Corresponds to the [`TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html#TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES)
 constant which is part of the [`TextView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) Android Class. This class is wrapped by the `Androidapi.JNI.Widget.JTextView` interface but this is not used directly by the Firemonkey TEdit controls, instead Firemonkey uses a proxy class called `JFMXTextEditorProxy`. so in theory you must access the proxy class linked to the EditControl to set the  value `TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES` using the `setEnterAction` method. unfortunately the instance to this proxy class is encapsuled in the `TTextServiceAndroid` class which is defined in the implementation part of the `FMX.Platform.Android` unit, **so can't be accessed**. So the only option which come to my mind is use the `OnKeyDown` event like :

This will Capitalize the first letter of the EditText and any after a space character.

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; var KeyChar: Char;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if  (TEdit(Sender).Text.Length=0) or ((TEdit(Sender).Text.Length>0) and  TEdit(Sender).Text.EndsWith(' ')) then
     KeyChar:=UpCase(KeyChar);
end;
```

Comment: Yes. I tried that way, but it is not an option for me. I need user to see Capitalized first letter when he typing words, not when hi types " ". May be it is some way to "press" shift in Virtual Keybord? I think it must be.