# FireMonkey first char capitalization in Android

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, capitalization

I would like to know if it's possible to disable the first char capitalization to the FireMonkey TMemo control for Android, I'm using Delphi XE7.
Strangely, I've seem [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372158/can-i-set-inputtype-to-textcapsentences-delphi-xe5) at StackOverflow asking about how to enable such functionality, but in my case I can't get rid of it.
I built an application where I can enter small textual commands to setup the functionality of certain operations, but these commands are case sensitive. It's really annoying have to disable the shift key before enter each one.
I tried to find examples at the Embarcadero documentation, but it seems this option does not exist. Is that the case?

Comment: Auto capitalization is a user setting of the device http://www.greenbot.com/article/2453381/type-in-style-how-to-change-your-android-keyboard.html

Comment: Yeah, but there are some Android file editors that implement what I need. [This application](http://www.apk4fun.com/apk/1578/) even add the syntax highlighting while avoiding the default first char capitalization.
As far as I can see, I will have to hardcode this functionality in my application.

Comment: In OnChange and OnTyping change the text of the edit to lower case. Could even set it up so it only happens if the length of the text is 1.